# Find unitary matrix so that $ P^{-1}BP$ is diagonal.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

given is the matrix

$ B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & i & -i \\ -i & 2 & 0 \\ i & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix} $.

I have to find a matrix $P \in U(3)$ (in unitary group, meaning that $P^{-1}$ = transposed compex-conjugated P) so that $P^{-1}BP$ is diagonal matrix.

I'm afraid I have no idea how to do this.
I thought about something with eigenvalue and eigenvectors?

Comment: Find eigenvalues and an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors, arrange these into the columns of $P$.

Comment: Hi! characteristic polynomial is $-t^3 + 5t^2 -6t$, eigenvalues 0,2,3. The eigenvectors as columns are then $\begin{pmatrix} 2i & 0 & -i \\ -1 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, correct?

Comment: The third column is not an eigenvector - probably a calculation mistake. Furthermore, you need the set of eigenvectors to be ortho*normal*, not just orthogonal, so some scaling will be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & i & -i \\ -i & 2 & 0 \\ i & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$Q = \begin{pmatrix} i & -1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ -2i & -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$D = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Then
$$B = Q^{-1}DQ$$
and
$$D=QBQ^{-1}=:P^{-1}BP$$

$$P=Q^{-1}=\frac{1}{6}\begin{pmatrix} -2i & 0 & 2i \\ -2 & 3 & -1 \\ 2 & 3 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$